# python iterators and thread-safety

Tags: python, multithreading, iterator, thread-safety, atomic

I have a class which is being operated on by two functions. One function creates a list of widgets and writes it into the class:

```
def updateWidgets(self):
   widgets = self.generateWidgetList()
   self.widgets = widgets
```

the other function deals with the widgets in some way:

```
def workOnWidgets(self):
   for widget in self.widgets:
      self.workOnWidget(widget)
```

each of these functions runs in it's own thread. the question is, what happens if the `updateWidgets()` thread executes while the `workOnWidgets()` thread is running?

I am assuming that the iterator created as part of the `for...in` loop will keep some kind of reference to the *old* self.widgets object? So I will finish iterating over the old list... but I'd love to know for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`updateWidgets()` doesn't alter `self.widgets` in place (which would have been a problem) but rather replaces it with a new list. The references to the old one are kept at least until the `for` loop in `workOnWidgets()` has finished, so this should not be a problem.

Simplified, what you're doing is kind of like this:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> for i in l:
...    l=[]
...    print(i)
...
1
2
3
```

However, you'd be running into problems if you modified the list you're iterating over:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> for i in l:
...    l[2]=0
...    print(i)
...
1
2
0
```